# Angular ng-repeat render items on top of list but keeping scroll to currently visible item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, scroll-position

I have the following problem: I want to make items visible in the beginning of my ng-repeat that were previously hidden. When I do this, the list of items eventually becomes longer and all the elements that were rendered before move down. I want to keep the scroll position at the item that was focused before I showed the new items.

```
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:listEndIndex" ng-if="$index >= listStartIndex">
```

This is the code of my template. My controller decreases the value of listStartIndex to make new items visible. Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!